# Does android's DownloadManager automatically queue downloads for later even if they're from a local server, when network doesn't have internet?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, android-download-manager

My application uses DownloadManager to pull files it needs from a local server (expressjs), and this works fine when the network has internet.  The actual use case is on an airgapped network, and it seems like DownloadManager never attempts to download the file in this situation (no cellular service, wifi only, wifi doesn't have internet).  In the airgapped situation that my application is failing to download, I'm able to use chrome on the device to navigate to the same url that DownloadManager uses and download the file successfully.

Is this a default behavior for DownloadManager, and if so, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

`DownloadManager` only handles `HTTP` requests. check this -https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html

> The download manager is a system service that handles long-running
>   HTTP downloads. Clients may request that a URI be downloaded to a
>   particular destination file. The download manager will conduct the
>   download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and
>   retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and
>   system reboots.

you should avoid using your local server url.

Comment: I've read that but it doesn't explain possible queueing behavior like what i'm seeing.  the requests are http (i'm hitting an express server i.e. http://192.168.3.4:3003/folder/file.ext ) and if nothing changes other than the wifi network gaining an internet connection it seems to be fine.